# How do I build a neural network model that takes in a list of tuples

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to make an AI using Keras model that learns how to play pong. The input that my current model takes in is a list of tuple of agent.rect which is taken from pygame.Rect() function and agent.rect.center alongside with the bot that I coded and the ball of the game. How do I build a kind of model that takes in that type of input and outputs a proper result.

I've tried changing the input_dim to 18 from the original code, but it wouldn't work

This is my model

```py
def network(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=120, activation='relu', input_dim=6))
        model.add(Dropout(0.15))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=120, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.15))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=120, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.15))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=3, activation='softmax'))
        opt = Adam(self.learning_rate)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
        return model
```

This is the state I tried to put in

```py
def get_state(self, pong, player, bot):

        state = [player.rect, player.rect.center, pong.rect, pong.rect.center, bot.rect, bot.rect.center]
        self.length = len(state)
        return np.asarray(state)
```

And this is where the error is

```py
print self.model.predict(np.array(next_state))
                target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(np.array([next_state]))[0])
            target_f = self.model.predict(np.array([state]))
            target_f[0][np.argmax(action)] = target
            self.model.fit(np.array([state]), target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

The error output is ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n_output = 3

def network(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(n_output, activation='softmax'))
        opt = Adam(self.learning_rate)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
        return model
```

Comment: it didn't work. The error it outputs is ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: well without showing us your input data, nobody can help - the error is your input data - it seems to have only 1 column and not 6.